# How to speed up the code for k-max subarray sum

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

Consider an array A of integers of length n.  The k-max subarray sum asks us to find up to k (contiguous) non-overlapping subarrays of A with maximum sum.  If A is all negative then this sum will be 0. If A = [-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2] for example, then the two subarrays could be [2, -1, 2] and [2, 2] with total sum 7.

The following code is my extension of [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)  and runs in O(nk) time, which might be optimal.

```
def solve_SO(test_seq, k=2):
    """
    Computes the k max subarray sum
    """
    num_intervals = k * 2 + 1
    t = None
    best = np.zeros(num_intervals, dtype=int)
    for seq_idx, val in enumerate(test_seq):
        # Add the current value to all the "include" interval best scores
        for interval_idx in range(1, num_intervals, 2):
            best[interval_idx] += val
        # Go over all intervals from the first include one.
        # If we were better off without, update the best score to be the best
        # from the previous interval. This makes best monotonic.
        # The final value is the current best score overall
        for interval_idx in range(1, num_intervals):
            if best[interval_idx] < best[interval_idx - 1]:
                best[interval_idx] = best[interval_idx - 1]
    return best[num_intervals - 1]
```

We can test it with:

```
solve_SO([-1, 2, -1, 2, -1], 2)
Out[22]: 4

In [23]: solve_SO([-1, 2, -1, 2, -1], 1)
Out[23]: 3
```

But my code seems inefficient. If k=3 for example, it makes an auxiliary array of length 7 and for every index in the input array it goes through the entire auxiliary array from index 1 to the end.

Can the code be made faster/more efficient when k is reasonably large?

Comment: Wouldn't a lower rated OP instantly be told to post this question on code review instead?

Comment: @SimonGoater Is that a better place for this sort of question? It is partly an algorithms question.

Comment: I don't actually know. But requests for faster/more efficient code often seem to be directed there.

Comment: @SimonGoater Performance questions are *on-topic* on StackOverflow (hence the `[performance]` tag). See [Performance question - Stack Overflow or Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review). However, the OP needs to make the question precise (which is the case), share profiling/performance information for pure performance question (can be improved), and the code should be working/reproducible (which is also the case here). Code reviews is about general improvements (less focused) on codes that may not even be reproducible.

Comment: but what should be the result? shouldn't be k-sublists?

Comment: "Can the code be made faster/more efficient..." - probably not, unless you port the equivalent code to a faster language. If you're looking for a better algorithm though, that's a different story; a worst-case linearithmic algorithm involving a priority queue should be possible.

Comment: @cards The output can be a single integer

Comment: @wLui155 Do you think it is necessary to have an auxiliary array of length 2k+1 that you go through n times?

Comment: As is, it seems you do need the length 2k + 1 array to store both include/not-include combinations, along with iterating n times to handle each and every element. I believe a more efficient approach would involve trying to partition the maximum subarrays into regions, divided by the terms that aren't a part of any maximum subarray. From there, depending on the value of k, you'd either: a) accept a subset of the maximum subarrays or b) take all of the maximum subarrays, but drop various negative terms from them.

Comment: @wLui155 That sounds really good. Do you think you could implement it?

Comment: Actually what are the constraints to your problem? My algorithm ended up breaking on some test cases and I have a feeling that you're not going to be able to do much better than O(n * k) in the worst case. However, there are some tricks you can do to speed up the approach for some data if k is very large; for example, if k is relative to n and there are less than or equal to k positive numbers in the array, you can simply include all of them in your result.

Comment: @wLui155 We can assume k will be no more than sqrt(n) if that helps simplify things.